# Physical Screen Resolution Size Changes In Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

MFC aplication when  used in remote desktop session gives in-correct screen resolution.
I have an mfc application TestMFC. On my machine if I use

```
HDC screen = ::GetDC(0);
int dpiX = GetDeviceCaps (screen, HORZSIZE);
int dpiY = GetDeviceCaps (screen, VERTSIZE);
```

gives me out 564 and 318 while when my application is executing in remote desktop session it gives out 320 and 240. While Pixel size remain same 1600 & 900.
I am using full screen setting in remote desktop screen settings.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You are hoping that the remote machine will send back info about its monitor.  Even though you can change the size of the window dynamically.  It just doesn't.

Comment: what I want is to have an image drawing of let's say 10* 10 mm size on any device. For that I am using MM_LOMETRIC.So it works fine for both monitors and printers. But when using same application on some remote machine by using remote desktop. It zoom it. I tried to get screen logical extents in both cases and it returned different values of extents. So My question is why I am getting different values for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

HORZSIZE attempts to return the physical size of the screen in mm (when the information is available). You should use HORZRES for pixels.

Comment: He already does that.  Quote: "While pixel size remain the same".